# Getting Screen width and height in Android

Tags: android, random, screen-resolution, screen-size, android-screen-support

I am using this code to get my screen width and height and send my button to a random position on the screen but sometimes my button is completely off-screen. I don't believe that the resolution my code gets me is the true res.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
float height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
float width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

float maxX = width;
float maxY = height;
float minX = width/10;
float minY = height/15;

Random rand = new Random();

float finalX = rand.nextFloat() * abs(maxX - minX);
float finalY = rand.nextFloat() * abs(maxY - minY);

_height.setText("Current Y: " + String.valueOf(finalY));
_width.setText("Current X: " + String.valueOf(finalX));
max_height.setText("Max height: " + String.valueOf(height));
max_width.setText("Max width: " + String.valueOf(width));
btnClick.setX(finalX);
btnClick.setY(finalY);
btnClick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/width"
tools:context="com.jamblatech.clicker.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonEnd"
    android:layout_width="363dp"
    android:layout_height="572dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/zero"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerView"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:text="@string/zero"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.937" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/clickbutton"
    android:text="@string/Click"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewCount" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReplay"
    android:layout_width="221dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:text="@string/Replay"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Back"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.674" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/highScore"
    android:layout_width="261dp"
    android:layout_height="107dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.149" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/height"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/width"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maxheight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maxwidth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.09" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testTExt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Test"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startTimerText"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:text="@string/Test_number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.54" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here are 2 pictures displaying my problem:

1. Button slightly on-screen:
   [image: Button slightly on-screen]
2. Button completely off-screen:
   [image: Button completely off-screen]

Comment: Can you share your xml file also?

Comment: I have added the XML :)

Comment: Try replacing the ConstraintLayout with a RelativeLayout

Comment: Don’t replace ConstraintLayout, simply learn how to use it. The problem you’re having is unrelated. You need to translate the button in the layout by modifying the layout parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:
you already have randomly generated x and y,
 `x + button.getWidth()` to it and check if it is less than `screen width` if yes your x is well in bound if no regerenate your random x and y, similary if x is in bound do it for y and check y + button.getHeight() is less than `screen height` it will do.